# Regex for filter

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following .NET regex that isn't working when

1. There is a space in the 'val' group
2. The 'val' group isn't surrounded by single quotes

I'm after a Regex solution (not a parser) to modify this pattern to match the above two problems. Can someone with a bit more Regex experience improve it?

(?<field>\w+|`.+`|\[.+\])\s*(?<operator>[=<>]|LIKE)\s*(?<quote>'?)(?<val>(?:[\S-[']]|(?:''))+)(?:\k<quote>\B)?(?:\s*(?<boolean>(?:AND)|(?:OR))\s*)?

[REGEX STORM .Net Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3cfield%3e%5cw%2b%7c%60.%2b%60%7c%5c%5b.%2b%5c%5d%29%5cs*%28%3f%3coperand%3e%5b%3d%3c%3e%5d%7cLIKE%29%5cs*%28%3f%3cquote%3e%27%3f%29%28%3f%3cval%3e%28%3f%3a%5b%5cS-%5b%27%5d%5d%7c%28%3f%3a%27%27%29%29%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5ck%3cquote%3e%5cB%29%3f%28%3f%3a%5cs*%28%3f%3cboolean%3e%28%3f%3aAND%29%7c%28%3f%3aOR%29%29%5cs*%29%3f&i=a+LIKE+%27b%5b*%5d%27+OR+%5bb%5d+LIKE+%27c%27%27s%27+AND+d+%3d+f+OR+e+%3d+%27+d+%27%0d%0a%5ba+b%5d+%3d+%27d%27%0d%0a%60e+f+g%60+%3e+%27f%27%0d%0ag+%3c+4%0d%0ah+%3d+%27+%27%0d%0ai+%3d+%273+%27%0d%0a%5bFull+Name%5d+%3d+%27%27%0d%0aFirstName+LIKE+%27hello%27%0d%0a%5bFirstName%5d+%3d+%27g%27%0d%0a%60Age%60+%3e+6%0d%0a%60Full+Name%60+%3d+%27%27)
The pattern uses character sequence subtraction - does regex101 support this?

Capture groups:
Fields can optionally be surrounded by grave (`) or brackets ([]) if the field contains spaces or non-alphanumeric.

Values can be surrounded by single quotes ('). Escape a single quote using two single quotes. Escape wildcards '*' and '%' using square brackets "[*]" and "[%]". Escape square brackets '[' and ']' with square brackets "[[]" and "[]]"

Boolean operators can be OR or AND

Comparison operators can be =, <, > or LIKE

Pattern is simplification of [Microsoft Expression Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2) to only handle the above subset.

Examples that should work are below.
Each example is on a separate line. The regex can match multiple times on each line.
For example:

"a LIKE 'b[*]' OR [b] LIKE 'c''s' AND d = f OR e = ' d '" would match:

1. "a LIKE 'b[*]' OR". Groups for this match: field="a", operator=LIKE, val="b[*]", boolean=OR.
2. "[b] LIKE 'c''s' AND". Groups: field="b", operator=LIKE, val="c's", boolean=AND.
3. "d = f OR". Groups: field="d", operator="=", val="f", boolean=OR.
4. "e = ' d '". Groups: field="e", operator="=", val=" d ", boolean=. But the regex isn't matching this text.

> a LIKE 'b[*]' OR [b] LIKE 'c''s' AND d = f OR e = ' d '
>   [a b] = 'd'
>   `e f g` > 'f'
>   g < 4
>   h = ' '
>   i = '3 '
>   [Full Name] = ''
>   FirstName LIKE 'hello'
>   [FirstName] = 'g'
>   `Age` > 6
>   `Full Name` = ''

Comment: You are parsing SQL with regex? Prepare to be disappointed, SQL is away too variant to parse it with regex. Same thing with HTML. It's also considered bad practice, altho people try over and over again. Use SQL parser to get is out quick, easy and stable.

Comment: I don't want to parse full SQL. I'd just like to know if I can change this regex pattern to also match val group with and without spaces. And val group with or without surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use .net version from here to save you a lot of time and trouble?

[SQL parsers for .net](http://www.sqlparser.com/download.php)

I must admit I am not speaking from experience with those parsers but I do from similar problems people had with HTML / CSS parsing when they used regexes (including myself when younger) instead of a parser.

It's much more readable, less error-prone, easier to debug or maintain and takes less total time if you take the parser approach.

For example:

```
TGSqlParser sqlparser = new TGSqlParser(EDbVendor.dbvmysql);
        sqlparser.sqltext = "ALTER TABLE `world`.`t1` ALTER `c1` SET DEFAULT 'abc';";
        Assert.IsTrue(sqlparser.parse() == 0);

        TAlterTableStatement alterTableStatement = (TAlterTableStatement)sqlparser.sqlstatements.get(0);
        TAlterTableOption alterTableOption = alterTableStatement.AlterTableOptionList.getAlterTableOption(0);
        Assert.IsTrue(alterTableOption.OptionType == EAlterTableOptionType.AlterColumn);
        Assert.IsTrue(alterTableOption.DefaultExpr.ToString().Equals("'abc'", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Shows how to successfully extract the value of DEFAULT from alter table statement:

```
"ALTER TABLE `world`.`t1` ALTER `c1` SET DEFAULT 'abc';";
```

I am sure you can do something similar with your statements, just pass whatever string you are parsing instead of the hardcoded text.

I am sorry this is not a complete (on the platter, copy-paste) type of answer, I would put this in the comment if I thought it would showcase nicely. Hopefully, this way, when you see the simplicity of it, you will change your mind.

I am not in any way affiliated to the author nor do I recommend to use this if you find something that suits you better, all I am saying is use this APPROACH and showcasing a demo of it in action.

Comment: I understand. I might want to be disappointed. Although I don't/want need complete SQL parsing. I would like to know if someone who knows regex better than me can provide a pattern that can also match val capture group when quotes aren't used; Also match when quotes are used and there are spaces in the val. Purely from a regex solution instead of a parser.